# AAPT: error: '@tools:sample/avatars' is incompatible with attribute src (attr) reference|color

Tags: android, android-studio, android-developer-api

2

I am new to Android dev and am working on my first app. I have been running into trouble trying to get an image view set up with my own image (stock photos on studio are working fine), and am getting the following error:

AAPT: error: '@tools:sample/avatars' is incompatible with attribute src (attr) reference|color.

What this error means.
How to troubleshoot this.
Where my mistake lies.**

[this is the error it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNSw1.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5):

In the latest Android Studio, there is a default avatar image added when you drag and drop an ImageView to the Component Tree, and it'll add the line `android:src="@tools:sample/avatars"` to the ImageView tag by default. If you are replacing the default image with your custom_image Android Studio will automatically add another line `app:srcCompat="@drawable/custom_image"` to the ImageView tag, but it doesn't remove the existing default avatar image reference. Removing `android:src="@tools:sample/avatars"` line from the ImageView tag helped me to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

delete `android:src="@tools:sample/avatars"`
and edit the line `app:srcCompat="@drawable/custom_img" />`
to
`android:src="@drawable/custom_img"/>`